# App didn't work after adding firebase dependencies

Tags: java, android, android-studio, aide

I tried adding firebase dependencies and my app start crashing without showing logcat, then I tested it with firebase test lab, then I saw this Fatal Exception. Please help me out.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.edu.ae.Applications: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.edu.ae.Applications" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.edu.ae-_Z-yzsqBFr0um-xAQ9ruKQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.edu.ae-_Z-yzsqBFr0um-xAQ9ruKQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
       FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.edu.ae, PID: 19557
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.edu.ae.Applications: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.edu.ae.Applications" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.edu.ae-_Z-yzsqBFr0um-xAQ9ruKQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.edu.ae-_Z-yzsqBFr0um-xAQ9ruKQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1226)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6431)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.edu.ae.Applications" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.edu.ae-_Z-yzsqBFr0um-xAQ9ruKQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.edu.ae-_Z-yzsqBFr0um-xAQ9ruKQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1155)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1218)
    ... 9 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.edu.ae-_Z-yzsqBFr0um-xAQ9ruKQ==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.edu.ae-_Z-yzsqBFr0um-xAQ9ruKQ==/base.apk': Field's class index unexpected, 63vs 62
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:365)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:107)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:444)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:403)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:851)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:950)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1188)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2462)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6343)
        ... 8 more
```

I restarted the project to see if it would work
Here is the Applications.java, as for the MainActivity, I didn't add any code to it

```
package com.edu.ae;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class Applications extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtExceptionHandler;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.uncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DebugActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("error", getStackTrace(ex));
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 11111, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1000, pendingIntent);
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(2);
                uncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
            }
        });
        super.onCreate();
    }
    private String getStackTrace(Throwable th){
        final Writer result = new StringWriter();
        final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
        Throwable cause = th;
        while(cause != null){
            cause.printStackTrace(printWriter);
            cause = cause.getCause();
        }
        final String stacktraceAsString = result.toString();
        printWriter.close();
        return stacktraceAsString;
    }
    
}
```

I forgot to mention that while building, it shows "failed to merge dex"

Comment: ClassNotFoundException is usually due to Activity not included in Manifest.xml. Show me your manifest file.